# Application of Taylor's theorem in inequalities.

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Using Taylor's theorem to show that :
>   $$\forall x>0 \qquad 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} < e^x < 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} e^x$$

What I see is, its starting terms resembles the expansion of 
maclaurin series of $e^x$, is that someway relevant?

In fact i can solve it without taylor's theorem, buy observing the signs of $f'(x)$ in various subsets of real line, I will prove the left side and then right, but I don't think this is the efficient way to do it.

Comment: These inequalities are only true for $x>0$, not $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), if $f(x)=e^x$ then for some $0<t<x$,
$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(t)x^2}{2}$$
that is
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{e^tx^2}{2}.$$
The given inequalities follow from the fact that $1=e^0<e^t<e^x$.

Comment: If i have something to prove like $\cos(x) \geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ ,then how to proceed ?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=\cos(x)-1+x^2/2$ and show that it has a minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Ya,i can do it that way,but how to do it using taylors theorem,should i neglect the reminder term ?

Comment: Check the remainder term of order $4$th

Comment: I mean can i just write ,$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R_4$ so $\cos x \geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: You have to show that $R_4\geq 0$.

Comment: $R_4=\frac{x^4}{4!} \cos(\theta x)$ where $\theta$ varries from 0 to 1, how it (cosine) is always $\geq 0$ ?

Comment: Taylor's remainder $R_4$ shows that the inequality holds in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. The inequality is trivial outside $[-2,2]$. You may use $R_5$ in the rest.